# static IP address for remote administration of a distant home computer via ssh?

Tags: ssh, remote, dhcp, administration

I've set up the PC of my grandmother with Debian and DHCP. I have to administer that PC, so the best option is obviously ssh. The problem with that is just DHCP changes obviously the IP address from time to time, so I can't rely on that.

- **=>** Is configuring that pc for a static IP a good way to solve that problem?
- **=>** Should I set up a script which emails me the IP address, if it has changed?
- **=>** or generally something else?

Comment: I presume you are only asking about the dynamic addressing on her home router, not her ISP, is that correct?  What make and model of device is serving up her DHCP addresses?

Comment: Well, not the home router - her home computer. I actually don't know the model number of her router, i just know it's the default Telekom Speedport

Comment: The internal IP (which is assigned by DHCP) will not be accessible remotely. You will need the external IP given to the router by the ISP. Use dynamic DNS (e.g. freedns.afraid.org) to automatically update the external IP and make it accessible via a consistent domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static IP is your best choice.

Another choice would be to have her DHCP server (the home route I suppose) always give out the same IP address to the MAC address of her network card. How that is done depends on the DHCP server. This servers the same purpose as a static IP, just moves the configuration away from the computer to the DHCP server.

Comment: Oh, and since your accessing the computer from outside her home network, disable password login to SSH and use keys.